# Set the current Value of UITextField to a property when UITextField's "editingDidBegin" control event fire

Tags: ios, objective-c, properties, uitextfield, uicontrolevents

How to set the current value of `UITextField` to a property(through a custom setter) declared in category which extends `UITextField` class when firing `editingDidBegin` control event of `UITextField`?

Comment: Explain your question briefly.

Comment: I want to get the current value of UITextField  to a variable when "UIControlEventEditingDidBegin" control event fires. I also want to add this behavour to all of my UITextField objects to check whether textfield value is edited or not. So I created a category which extends UITextField class and add a public property to store the value and now I want to set the textfield's value to this property when "UIControlEventEditingDidBegin" UITextcField's control event fires . Thanks ...

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this using a category by taking advantage of Associative References.

[From the docs:](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocAssociativeReferences.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH24-SW1)

> Using associative references, you can add storage to an object without
>   modifying the class declaration.

Here's an example that will get you going in the right direction:

**.h file**:

```
@interface UITextField (StoredProperty)

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *testString;

@end
```

**.m file**:

```
#import <objc/runtime.h>

static void *MyStoredPropertyKey = &MyStoredPropertyKey;

@implementation UITextField (StoredProperty)

- (NSString *)testString {
    return objc_getAssociatedObject(self, MyStoredPropertyKey);
}

- (void)setTestString:(NSString *)testString {
    objc_setAssociatedObject(self, MyStoredPropertyKey, testString, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC); 
}

@end
```

**Example use**:

```
NSObject *obj = [NSObject new];
obj.testString = @"This is my test string";
NSLog(@"%@", obj.testString);
```

Comment: Thanks @ tww0003 for your answer. I also followed associative references. But how to set the UITextField's value to "testString" property when "UIControlEventEditingDidBegin" control event fire?

Comment: @PSkyMax You could create another category, but this time for UITextFieldDelegate and set it in the `textFieldDidBeginEditing:` method.  Hope this helped, and if it did don't forget to mark the answer as accepted! Here's the relevant documentation: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextfielddelegate/1619590-textfielddidbeginediting?language=objc